# Одинаковая ссылка на свойства объектов

Tags: python, массивы, ооп, переменные

Возникла проблема, что на две переменные в разных объектах, созданных из одного класса, ссылается одна и та же ссылка. Значение этих переменных задаётся во время создания класса при помощи конструктора.

Особенность в том, что эти объекты находятся внутри массива, свойства третьего объекта созданного другим классом.

```
class Engine ():

    objects = [] 

    def __init__ (self):
        pass
```

```
class Obstacle:

    xy = [0,0]

    def __init__(self, x, y):
        self.xy[0] = x
        self.xy[1] = y
```

```
engine = Engine ()
engine.objects.append (Obstacle(4, 4))      
engine.objects.append (Obstacle(6, 6))
```

При выводе массива *xy*, значение равно *[6,6]*.

Код ниже выводит *True*.

```
print (engine.objects[0].xy is engine.objects[1].xy)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Проблема тут:

```
class Obstacle:

    xy = [0,0]
```

Тут `xy` - переменная класса, т.е. она привязана не к конкретному экземпляру класса, а одна для всех экземпляров.

Делайте так:

```
class Obstacle:

    def __init__(self, x, y):
        self.xy = [0, 0]
        self.xy[0] = x
        self.xy[1] = y
```

Можно еще более упростить:

```
class Obstacle:

    def __init__(self, x, y):
        self.xy = [x, y]
```

Answer (score 1):

Видимо тут код переписывался после знакомства с Java/C# или чем-то подобным. Поля `objects` и `xy`, объявленные таким образом в питоне являются **статическими**, т.е. разделяются между всеми экземплярами класса. Синтаксически они никак не отличаются от нестатических. Нестатические поля создаются в конструкторе:

```
class Engine ():
    def __init__ (self):
        self.objects = []

class Obstacle:
    def __init__(self, x, y):
        self.xy = [x, y]
```